# Leaflet make polyline from GeoJson

Tags: real-time, leaflet, geojson, polyline

Can someone help me maybe? I have 4 markers and one of them is a **Master PC** his and other 3 **worker node's** that are connected to a polyline. For this I added in GeoJSON at properties the "PC".

Tells you maybe how I can implement it?

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [
{"type": "Feature","properties": {"id":"1","name":"Berlin","wert":"","pc":"master"},"geometry": {"type": "Point","coordinates": [13.523563700000068,52.4909447]}},
{"type": "Feature","properties": {"id":"2","name":"Hamburg","wert":"0","pc":"wn"},"geometry": {"type": "Point","coordinates": [9.99368179999999,53.5510846]}},
{"type": "Feature","properties": {"id":"3","name":"München","wert":"128","pc":"wn"},"geometry": {"type": "Point","coordinates": [11.581980599999952,48.1351253]}},
{"type": "Feature","properties": {"id":"4","name":"Frankfurt am Main","wert":"-128","pc":"wn"},"geometry": {"type": "Point","coordinates": [8.682126700000026,50.1109221]}}
```

]
}